How to make Safari Frequently Visited option to work
I’m on iPhone 13 Pro iOS 17.4.1 and I’m trying to get Safari Frequently Visited sites option to work. It’s never worked on this phone which was new and set up as new. I’ve toggled the option off/on numerous times and shutting phone down in between this. Restarted Safari also. Have also done hard reboot of phone. Nothing has helped.
Anyone know how I can get it to work?  What am I missing?  See pics below , option active- not showing.
Should be under Favorites



Anyone??  Any tips appreciated.

Heard back from Apple - they said to use Bookmarks - they have no control over the Safari setting Frequently Visited.  Odd....

Any have anyway to get this feature to work - still trying to get it to show….  Tks!
